# Is this right? A jQuery bug that erases the data store?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fire up your firebug console and try this out.

Compare this:

```
$('body').data('x',1);
$(thisx).remove();
console.log($('body').data('x'));
```

to this:

```
$('body').data('x',1);
$(this.x).remove();
console.log($('body').data('x'));
```

Notice the difference? If `thisx` is undefined, it will immediatly throw a reference error. If `x` is an undefined property of `this`, jQuery will return the document as it's result set instead. Next jQuery will attempt to remove your document (which it can't), but before doing that it will remove all data attached to any child element of the document. **Thus, wiping out your data store.**

Note: `this` can be any element reference or object. You only need to have jQuery attempt to access an undefined property.

*(Talk about a pain. It fails silently, and I'm trying to figure out why my data is suddenly missing. I track it down to a special case where an element reference was undefined in a specific situation.)*

So on to my questions:

1) **Before I submit a bug report**, am I analyzing this correctly? Also if someone happens to know that this is a known issue, let me know. I couldn't find it in the bug tracker, but the interface isn't that great (or maybe I have this wrong).

2) Why is there ultimately any difference? I'm guessing `thisx` is evaluated immediately which causes the exception while `this.x` is a reference that is passed and evaluated in the called function, right? (where I think the line `selector = selector || document`; is the culprit.

3) **Suggestions for how to handle this?** I guess I should be checking that **any/every** element reference or property of an object (e.g. stored selector strings) is defined before I pass it to jQuery when removing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is there ultimately any difference?

Both `thisx` and `this.x` are evaluated when the function is called. The first one refers to an undefined variable name and this throws a reference error. The second one accesses an undefined property of an object, which results in the value `undefined`. This is just how javascript behaves in these cases.

Now when JQuery is called in the second case, the call `$(this.x)` evaluates to `$(undefined)` which is the same as if you just would have called `$()`. Since it looks to JQuery as if no argument was provided, it uses a default instead, and in this case the default is `document`. Then it proceeds trying to delete `document`, since it was effectively called as  `$().remove()`, in which case this would be expected.

> Suggestions for how to handle this?

The difference with the `ReferenceError` is a fundamental Javascript difference, not much that can be done about that. JQuerys behavior is unfortunate and a consequence of setting defaults by `arg = arg||default`. One could user `arguments.length` instead to get the real number of call parameters, but a change like this would surely result in lot's of broken code that relied on the default being used when `undefined` or `0` is passed, so it's unlikely to happen.

Answer (score 3):

Try typing these into the console too (with no extra variables defined beforehand):

```
> a
    ReferenceError: Can't find variable: a
> b = {}
    Object
> b.a
    undefined
```

one is a javascript error, one silently returns undefined (which jQuery will interpret as `$()` because javascript and jQuery can't tell the functions `$()` and `$(undefined)` apart)

this is the way javascript works, bug or feature I leave open to debate, but I don't think that this is jQuery's fault or problem.

**edit:** why does jQuery have `$()` defined?

From the docs:

> By default, if no context is specified,
>   $() looks for DOM elements within the
>   context of the current HTML document.
>   If you do specify a context, such as a
>   DOM element or jQuery object, the
>   expression will be matched against the
>   contents of that context.

**edit**: the docs were referring to the context argument passed to `$()`, not to calling `$()` without arguments, so it isn't relevant here.

also note that

```
$().get(0) == $("").get(0)
```

Comment: I think it becomes problematic when undefined becomes the document element. Are there other cases where this is useful in jQuery?

Comment: Hmm .... I wonder if it might be better handled where $('') is used for that case. Not that they would change it now for legacy reasons. Still the code could distinguish between an empty string and an undefined value. It could also check the arguments length. An undefined value would still have a arguments.length == 1 whereas $() would be 0, right?